Neovim tabstops and git diff
I am new to vim and have difficulty setting it up.
I am working with a FRR code in which the tab is 8 spaces. I want to see 4 spaces instead of 8 and have added the following settings [options.lua]:
vim.opt.expandtab = true
vim.opt.shiftwidth = 4
vim.opt.tabstop = 4
vim.opt.smarttab = true
vim.opt.autoindent = true
vim.opt.smartindent = true

git shows new lines in the file as:
-       memset(&mroute, 0, sizeof(mroute));
+    memset(&mroute, 0, sizeof(mroute));
        stream_get(&mroute.sg.src, client->ibuf, 4);
        stream_get(&mroute.sg.grp, client->ibuf, 4);
 

I don't see the difference in the file itself, but git shows that it is there. How can this be fixed?

If you run git diff | cat -A as suggested by How to show space and tabs with git-diff does it show that tabs in the original file have been replaced with 4 spaces on the edited lines? The vim.opt.expandtab = true option might be causing VIM to replace tabs with spaces on edited lines. I'm not a VIM user, but basing that upon the neovim documentation.

i changed parameter expandtab to false and this works for me =)

I've never thought about the difference between tab and space. Thanks!

If you run git diff | cat -A as suggested by How to show space and tabs with git-diff I expect that it will show that  tabs in the original file have been replaced with 4 spaces on the edited lines.
From the NEOVIM documentation The vim.opt.expandtab = true will cause VIM to replace tabs with spaces on edited lines.
Therefore, suggest change the setting to vim.opt.expandtab = false
As an aside, I not sure what the FRR code is, but tabs being 8 chatacters matches the Linux kernel coding style Indentation. Not sure if editing the code with a tab of 4 characters, rather than 8, could cause inconsistent indentation to be inserted compared to the original tab of 8 characters.
